# Iterating through arrays in Assembly to solve general equation

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86-64, nasm

I'm in the process of learning Assembly language using NASM, and have run into a programming problem that I can't seem to figure out. The goal of the program is to solve this equation:
[Picture of Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BdGd.png)
For those unable to see the photo, the equation says that for two arrays of length n, array a and array b, find: for i=0 to n-1, ((ai + 3) - (bi - 4))

I'm only supposed to use three general registers, and I've figured out a code sample I think could possibly work, but I keep running into comma and operand errors with lines 16 and 19. I understand that in order to iterate through the array you need to move a pointer to each index, but since both arrays are of different values (array 1 is dw and array 2 is db) I am unsure how to account for that. I'm still very new to Assembly, and any help or pointers would be appreciated.
Here is a picture of my current code:
[Code Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqxp0.png)

```
       segment .data
  a         dw    12, 14, 16      ; array of three values        
  b         db    2, 4, 5         ; array of three values
  n         dw    3               ; length of both arrays
  result    dq    0               ; memory to result
      segment .text
      global main
  main:
      mov   rax, 0
      mov   rbx, 0
      mov   rdx, 0
  loop_start:
      cmp   rax, [n]
      jge   loop_end
      
      add   rbx, a[rax*4]   ; adding element of a at current index to rbx
      add   rbx, 3          ; adding 3 to current index value of array a in rbx
      
      add   rdx, BYTE b[rax]
      sub   rdx, 4

      sub   rbx, [rdx]
      add   [result], rbx
      
      xor   rbx, rbx
      xor   rdx, rdx
      add   rax, 1
  loop_end:
      ret
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using 16-bit and 8-bit data, but 64-bit registers.  Generally speaking, the processor requires the same data size though out the operands of any single instruction.

`cmp rax,[n]` has varying data size, which is not allowed: `rax` is a 64-bit register, and `[n]` is a 16 bit data item.  So, we can change this to `cmp ax,[n]`, and now everything is 16-bit.

`add rbx,a[rax*4]` is also mixing different size operands (not allowed).  `rbx` is 64-bits and `a[]` is 16-bits.  You can change the register to `bx` and this will be allowed.  But also let's note that `*4` is too much it should be `*2` since `dw` is 16-bit data (2-byte), not 32-bit (4-byte).  Since you're clearing `rbx`, you don't need an `add` here you can simply `mov`.

`add rdx, BYTE b[rax]` is also mixing different sizes.  `rax` is 64-bits wide whereas `b[]` is 8-bits wide.  Use `dl` instead of `rdx`.  There is nothing to add to with this so you should use a `mov` instead of `add`.  Now that there's a value in `dl`, and you previously cleared `rdx`, you can switch to using `dx` (from `dl`) this will have the 16-bit value of b[i].

`sub rbx, [rdx]` has an erroneous deference.  Here you just want to `sub bx,dx`.

You are not using the label `loop_start`, so there is no loop. (Add a backward branch at the end of the loop.)

Comment: In NASM, data declarations don't associate a size with the label.  `cmp rax,[n]` is fully allowed - the 64-bit register implies the operand size for the other operand.  It's of course not what you *want* to do (because the high 6 bytes you load come from `result: dq 0`), but that's just a bug in your program, not something the machine can't do.  Or to put it another way, NASM doesn't help you detect bugs like this.  It just assembles what you write.  Asm doesn't have variables, just raw bytes, and x86 allows misaligned loads.

Answer (score 2):

> ...but since both arrays are of different values (array 1 is `dw` and array 2 is `db`) I am unsure how to account for that

[Erik Eidt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62841586/iterating-through-arrays-in-assembly-to-solve-general-equation/62843044#62843044) explaines why you "keep running into comma and operand errors". Although you can revert to using the smaller registers (adding operand size prefixes), my answer takes a different approach.

The instruction set has the `movzx` (move with zero extension) and `movsx` (move with sign extension) instructions to deal with these varying sizes. See below how to use these.

I've applied a few changes too.

- Don't miss an opportunity to simplify your calculation:

  `((a[i] + 3) - (b[i] - 4))` is equivalent to `(a[i] - b[i] + 7)`
- None of these arrays is empty, so you can just put the loop condition below its body.
- You can process the arrays starting at the end if it's convenient. The summation operation doesn't mind!

```
     segment .data
a      dw    12, 14, 16      ; array of three values        
b      db    2, 4, 5         ; array of three values
n      dw    3               ; length of both arrays
result dq    0               ; memory to result
    segment .text
    global main
main:
       movzx rcx, word [n]
loop_start:
       movzx rax, word [a + rcx * 2 - 2]
       movzx rbx, byte [b + rcx - 1]
       lea   rax, [rax + rbx + 7]
       add   [result], rax
       dec   rcx
       jnz   loop_start
       ret
```

Please notice that the additional negative offsets `- 2` and `- 1` exist to compensate for the fact that the loop control takes on the values {3, 2, 1} when {2, 1, 0} would have been perfect. This does not introduce an extra displacement component to the instruction since the mention of the *a* and *b* arrays is in fact already the displacement.

Although this is tagged x86-64, you can write the whole thing using 32-bit registers and not require the REX prefixes. Same *result*.

```
     segment .data
a      dw    12, 14, 16      ; array of three values        
b      db    2, 4, 5         ; array of three values
n      dw    3               ; length of both arrays
result dq    0               ; memory to result
    segment .text
    global main
main:
       movzx ecx, word [n]
loop_start:
       movzx eax, word [a + ecx * 2 - 2]
       movzx ebx, byte [b + ecx - 1]
       lea   eax, [eax + ebx + 7]
       add   [result], eax
       dec   ecx
       jnz   loop_start
       ret
```

Comment: `[a + ecx * 2 - 2]` requires an address-size prefix to use 32-bit registers in an x86-64 addressing mode.  `movzx eax, word [a + rcx * 2 - 2]` would be the smallest and most efficient way to write that instruction.   We know that ECX is already correctly zero-extended into RCX.  Of course it's silly to have `n: dw 3` in memory at all; that should be `n equ $ - b` after `b`, and `mov ecx, n`.

Comment: Also, use `default rel` so addressing modes like `[result]` can be RIP-relative, instead of wasting a SIB byte to encode a 32-bit absolute (sign-extended) address.  Also, accumulating into a register store once after the loop would be more efficient, even though it would take an extra instruction.  Keeping loop variables in memory is very bad for performance (like debug-mode).  The original question does that, but if you're pointing out efficiency improvements, that's the most important for speed (although not for size)